# Mathematica 11.3 ListLogPlot gives strange error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, logarithmic-scale

Trying to make a very simple Log plot with Mathematica 11.3 on Ubuntu 17.10

```
$MinPrecision = 50; $MaxPrecision = Infinity;
xdata = {1, 2, 3};
ydata = {3.1477302095075719181822635235032484855701651103438435833662749813828`50.*^-10, 
1.67617205912971801959202031586091406033234727051978784055642146218626996127554`50.*^-19, 
1.17226083478094225310738147085522424615235140248269823593054063307967248`50.*^-25};
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}]]
```

which produces the following error message:

```
Tick specification must be a list or a function
```

Also a picture of the output

[image]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}]]
```

works fine.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with version 11.3 on macOS.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.10, added this to the question

Comment: Also not reproducible with 11.3 on Windows 10

Comment: Can't reproduce on *Mma11.2* nor *Mma11.3* on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is irreproducible.

Answer (score 1):

```
         ListLogPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}], Joined -> True, 
         PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledSquare]", 20, Blue], Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This seems to work, but without any options it still doesnt' work. Does it work for you without any options?

Comment: Yes, It is working without any option.